# Security rule to limit storage space used in Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

In Firestore I store the infos of space used (in Firebase Storage) and space total per user and I was wondering if I could use these variables to write a Storage rule to directly limit storage space per user there?

Is there any way to achieve that? Is it even useful?

Currently the rule I have allow users to only access their own storage folder :

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /users/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not immediately possible in security rules.  Storage security rules cannot access data in Firestore.  Similarly, Firestore security rules cannot access data in Storage.  So, it's not possible to stop a Storage upload from happening based on data that exists outside that product.

The best you can do to enforce a quota is to use a product like Cloud Functions to run a [Storage trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) *after* an upload completes, and check at that point if the upload caused the user to exceed any limits.  You can then choose to delete the file if you want.  You might also want to use a trigger to maintain a running total of usage per-user.